# JavaScript dynamic code to self execute function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem, but I can't solve it......

There is a function on the other website, so I can't modify it

The code is

And I want to add a protoype "aaa" to get `i(5)` return value

how can I do it?

```
(function () {
    function i(a) {
        return a + 1; //complex calculate...
    }

    window.Util = {
        n: i(1),
        windowUtil: i(2),
        Hub: i(3)
    };
})

eval("window.Util.aaa =  i(5) ");
```

But it error

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: I is not defined".....

Comment: `window.i  = function i(a) {`

Comment: I can't modify IIFE function, it's the code on the others websit

Comment: self invoking functions have to be invoked by adding `()` after their definition.

Comment: sir, I don't known what you men..

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues here

- `function` expression is defined but not invoked
- `i` is not exposed to global scope for `eval` to work.

**Demo**

```js
(function () {
    window.i = function i(a) {
        return a + 1; //complex calculate...
    }

    window.Util = {
        n: i(1),
        windowUtil: i(2),
        Hub: i(3)
    };
})();

console.log(eval("window.Util.aaa =  i(5) "));
```

Comment: I can't modify IIFE function, it's the code on the others websit

Comment: @user7831558 how are you getting code from other websites?

Comment: it's  javascript code ... you can see it on the client browser

Comment: So, if you are copying code some others website then why can't you modify the same?

Comment: I want to parsing data from others website , so I have to get the data from the js on the website     but the data is in the self function, I can't get it

Comment: Data and code are two different things, looks like you want to scrape the data from another website. Search for *web scrapping*.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `function i()` inside the self invoking function.Use it outside the self invoking function. Like this:

```js
function i(a) {
    return a + 1; //complex calculate...
}
(function () {
    window.util = {
        n: i(1),
        windowUtil: i(2),
        Hub: i(3)
    };
})()

alert(eval("window.util.aaa =  i(5)"))
```

Comment: I can't modify IIFE function, it's the code on the others websit  actually I want to get the data from the others website.......